# Inconsistent behavior concatenating bytes to list Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I encountered an error when trying to concatenate bytes and a list of ints. I managed to fix the issue, but I was wondering if anyone knows what was causing the weird behavior.

This works, and prints out `[1, 2, 3, 97, 98, 99]`:

```py
test_bytes = b'abc'
test_list = [1, 2, 3]
test_list += test_bytes
print(test_list)
```

However this doesn't and throws an error:

```py
test_bytes = b'abc'
test_list = [1, 2, 3]
test_list = test_list + test_bytes     # This line Changed
print(test_list)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rowan/Example/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    test_list = test_list + test_bytes
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "bytes") to list
```

Why does this happen, and is there any similar behavior that I should be watching out for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lists, `+=` roughly corresponds to [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) which takes an arbitrary iterable as an argument, hence it also works with a `str`:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
x = 'abc'
lst += x
print(lst)
# [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

`+` on the other hand, is stricter with regard to the operands it accepts if one of them is a `list`. You would have to cast the `str` to a `list`:

```
lst + list(x)
# [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Generally, the mutable built-in types implement the applicable updating operators (`+=, -=, &=`, ...) as mutations on the existing objects. For those, `a = a + b` and `a += b` are **not** the same, because the former create new objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well:

```
test_bytes = b'abc'
test_list = [1, 2, 3]
test_list.extend(test_bytes)

print(test_list)
```

Reason being concatination can work's on two mutable sequences and what you have tried in the non working code is concatination of a list with byte. Hence it throws `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "bytes") to list`.

Comment: That gives ```[1, 2, 3, b'abc']``` instead of ```[1, 2, 3, 97, 98, 99]```

Comment: Yea! but you have mentioned in the question that you have been trying to concatinate the two.

Comment: I guess concatenate is the wrong word then, sorry. I did say in the question that ```[1, 2, 3, 97, 98, 99]``` was my expected result

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operation on a list concatenates 2 lists together.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

new_list = list1 + list2
```

> new_list: [1,2,3,4,5,6]

What you want to do is `.append()` an item to an existing list, not make a new list:

```
test_bytes = b'abc'
test_list = [1, 2, 3]
for byte in test_bytes:
    test_list.append(byte)
```

> test_list: [1, 2, 3, 97, 98, 99]

This is interesting, I've never ran across this case.  You've found that python will treat a string of *bytes* as a *list* of bytes when using the `+=` operator, but as a single string of bytes when using the `+` operator.

I would guess, that like myself, this handling is unfamiliar to most python programmers, and would recommend treating the bytes individually, as shown above, in place of using the `+=` with existing bytes.

However, if you are planning to do *byte* manipulation, I would recommend using a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) instead of a list.